# В чем ошибка? При вводе возраста, выдаёт кучу ошибок

Tags: python, telebot

Код

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

name = ''
surname = ''
age = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1788126055:AAHmViL-7tG84l3IwsUxJ41zUpwQkDmnlPU')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, '''Привет!

Это бот для тестирования кода!''')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    if message.text == '/register':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Как вас зовут?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_name)

def reg_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какая у вас фамилия?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_surname)

def reg_surname(message):
    global surname
    surname = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Сколько вам лет?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_age)

def reg_age(message):
    global age
    while age == 0:
        try:
            age = int(message.text)
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вводите свой возраст цифрами!')

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(text = 'Да', callback_data = 'yes')
    keyboard.add(key_yes)
    key_no = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(text = 'Нет', callback_data = 'no')
    keyboard.add(key_no)
    question = 'Тебе ' + str(age) + ' лет и тебя зовут: ' + name + ' ' + surname + ' верно?'
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text = question, reply_merkup = keyboard)

bot.polling()
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Анастасия\Desktop\bot.py", line 50, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Users\Анастасия\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 496, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Анастасия\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 555, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Анастасия\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 518, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Анастасия\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 117, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Анастасия\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Анастасия\Desktop\bot.py", line 43, in reg_age
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(text = 'Да', callback_data = 'yes')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data="yes"))
keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data="no"))
```

все остальное вроде правильно

Comment: Поменял свои строки кода на ваши, но всё равно выдаёт такую же ошибку

Comment: @rezzos Вы внимательно заменили? Именно на те строки, что в ответе? Или скопипастили свои? InlineKeyboard**Button**